# mediapipe real time 3D coordinate printing

Tags: python, mediapipe

i would like to print a real time 3D Plot of the mediapipe 3D Landmarks.
I am able to get the holistic as shown below in real time from a Video File:
[image: Real Time Holistic]
Now i would like to plot the real time 3D Plot like this:

[image: Real Time Plot]

The code i used to plot the real time holistic is shown below. How i am able to plot the real time  Plot only from the holistic part ?

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import PyQt5
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import Video
import nb_helpers

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic 

file = 'walking.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

# Initiate holistic model
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        # Recolor Feed
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False        
        
        # Make Detections
        results = holistic.process(image)
        # print(results.face_landmarks)
        
        # face_landmarks, pose_landmarks, left_hand_landmarks, right_hand_landmarks
        
        # Recolor image back to BGR for rendering
        image.flags.writeable = True   
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        
        # 1. Draw face landmarks
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACEMESH_TESSELATION, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,110,10), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,256,121), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        
        # 2. Right hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,22,10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,44,121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )

        # 3. Left Hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,22,76), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,44,250), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )

        # 4. Pose Detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )
                        
        cv2.imshow('Raw Webcam Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would be grateful for any help !

Greets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below code , which I got from https://github.com/Kazuhito00/mediapipe-python-sample/blob/main/sample_pose.py

Below is the function you can include to plot the realtime 3d landmarks

```
def plot_world_landmarks(
    plt,
    ax,
    landmarks,
    visibility_th=0.5,
):
    landmark_point = []

    for index, landmark in enumerate(landmarks.landmark):
        landmark_point.append(
            [landmark.visibility, (landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z)])

    face_index_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    right_arm_index_list = [11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
    left_arm_index_list = [12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
    right_body_side_index_list = [11, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31]
    left_body_side_index_list = [12, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32]
    shoulder_index_list = [11, 12]
    waist_index_list = [23, 24]

    # 顔
    face_x, face_y, face_z = [], [], []
    for index in face_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        face_x.append(point[0])
        face_y.append(point[2])
        face_z.append(point[1] * (-1))

    # 右腕
    right_arm_x, right_arm_y, right_arm_z = [], [], []
    for index in right_arm_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        right_arm_x.append(point[0])
        right_arm_y.append(point[2])
        right_arm_z.append(point[1] * (-1))

    # 左腕
    left_arm_x, left_arm_y, left_arm_z = [], [], []
    for index in left_arm_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        left_arm_x.append(point[0])
        left_arm_y.append(point[2])
        left_arm_z.append(point[1] * (-1))

    # 右半身
    right_body_side_x, right_body_side_y, right_body_side_z = [], [], []
    for index in right_body_side_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        right_body_side_x.append(point[0])
        right_body_side_y.append(point[2])
        right_body_side_z.append(point[1] * (-1))

    # 左半身
    left_body_side_x, left_body_side_y, left_body_side_z = [], [], []
    for index in left_body_side_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        left_body_side_x.append(point[0])
        left_body_side_y.append(point[2])
        left_body_side_z.append(point[1] * (-1))

    # 肩
    shoulder_x, shoulder_y, shoulder_z = [], [], []
    for index in shoulder_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        shoulder_x.append(point[0])
        shoulder_y.append(point[2])
        shoulder_z.append(point[1] * (-1))

    # 腰
    waist_x, waist_y, waist_z = [], [], []
    for index in waist_index_list:
        point = landmark_point[index][1]
        waist_x.append(point[0])
        waist_y.append(point[2])
        waist_z.append(point[1] * (-1))
            
    ax.cla()
    ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)

    ax.scatter(face_x, face_y, face_z)
    ax.plot(right_arm_x, right_arm_y, right_arm_z)
    ax.plot(left_arm_x, left_arm_y, left_arm_z)
    ax.plot(right_body_side_x, right_body_side_y, right_body_side_z)
    ax.plot(left_body_side_x, left_body_side_y, left_body_side_z)
    ax.plot(shoulder_x, shoulder_y, shoulder_z)
    ax.plot(waist_x, waist_y, waist_z)
    
    plt.pause(.001)

    return
```